# How to use BindingNavigator programmatically?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net form and I'm trying to bind some data to controls.

I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub InitDataLayer()
    'Create table
    DataTable = New DataTable

    DataTable.Columns.Add("ID")
    DataTable.Columns("ID").DataType = GetType(Integer)
    DataTable.Columns("ID").AllowDBNull = False        

    DataTable.Columns.Add("Name")
    DataTable.Columns("Name").DataType = GetType(String)
    DataTable.Columns("Name").AllowDBNull = False

    'Create new rows
    '1st Row
    Dim NewRow As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRow.Item("ID") = 1
    NewRow.Item("Name") = "John"
    DataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    '2nd Row
    NewRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRow.Item("ID") = 2
    NewRow.Item("Name") = "Steve"
    DataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    'Bind controls
    'Textboxes
    TextBoxID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataTable, "ID"))
    TextBoxName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataTable, "Name"))

    'Navigator
    Dim BS As New BindingSource
    BS.DataSource = DataTable
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BS
End Sub
```

The code works but when I move to the second row in the binding navigator, the controls don't update (see [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qcnxp6bp7ao045/2013-11-21%2012h04_10.mp4))

What is missing to the code please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Private Sub InitDataLayer()
    'Create table
    DataTable = New DataTable

    DataTable.Columns.Add("ID")
    DataTable.Columns("ID").DataType = GetType(Integer)
    DataTable.Columns("ID").AllowDBNull = False        

    DataTable.Columns.Add("Name")
    DataTable.Columns("Name").DataType = GetType(String)
    DataTable.Columns("Name").AllowDBNull = False

    'Create new rows
    Dim NewRow As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRow.Item("ID") = 1
    NewRow.Item("Name") = "John"
    DataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    NewRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRow.Item("ID") = 2
    NewRow.Item("Name") = "Steve"
    DataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    'Bind controls
    Dim BS As New BindingSource
    BS.DataSource = DataTable

    TextBoxID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", BS, "ID"))
    TextBoxName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", BS, "Name"))

    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BS
End Sub
```